# multiple sequential recursive javascript functions for progress bar

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to call a recursive function repeatedly with different "percent" arguments so that they connect together into a progress bar on the front end. For example, I need to call the function five times with these percents:

`progress(21); progress(42); progress(64); progress(85); progress(100);`

I'm able to make my progress bar show `(21, 42, 64, 85, 100)`, but I want the progress bar for each function call to go from `(0-21, 22-42, 43-64, 65-85, 86-100)`.

It's okay if it doesn't finish its segment before the next function call. For example, `0-18, 22-40, 43-56`, etc...

It's okay if it has to wait on the upper end until the next function call. For example,

`0-21` (finishes before next function call and waits), `22-42, 43-64`, etc...

```
function progress(percent) {
  console.log(percent);

  $('.progress-bar span').css({
    width: percent + '%'
  });
  $('.progress-percent-done').text(percent + '%');

  var timeout = 500;
  if (percent < 100) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      progress(percent);
    }, timeout);
  }
}


//excerpt showing how progress function is called
beforeSend: function () {
    var batch_remainder = Math.max(0, ((batch_count + 1) * batch_size) - total_count);
    var percent = Math.round(((((batch_count + 1) * batch_size) - batch_remainder) / total_count) * 100);
    progress(percent);
...
```

Comment: You can just go from n to n via css `transition` property and then setting a specific duration.

Comment: You never change the value of `percent` inside the `progress` function which means that you're calling this function with the same value every time.

Comment: @AbanaClara Hi, yes I'm already doing that.

Comment: @Titus `percent` is a number that becomes available in another part of the code. Each time the `percent` number is available I want to call the `progress` function and have the progress bar on the front end move seamlessly up to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this via the use of promises, as follows:

```
function progress(percent) {
  console.log(percent);

  $('.progress-bar span').css({
    width: percent + '%'
  });
  $('.progress-percent-done').text(percent + '%');

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var timeout = 500;
    if (percent < 100) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        percent++; // Increment percent
        progress(percent);
      }, timeout);
    }
    else {
        resolve()
    }
  })

}

progress(21).then(function() {      
  return progress(42); 
})
.then(function() {
  return progress(64); 
})
.then(function() {
  return progress(85); 
})
.then(function() {
  return progress(100);
})
```

Comment: I'm calling the progress function in another part of the code when the "percent" number becomes available.

Comment: can you show how you're calling `progress()` and passing `percent` from the other part of your code?

Comment: I just added an edit to the main question above. Said it need to be peer reviewed first, so not sure if it's showing up for you. Also showing the `percent` variable. (don't laugh it that's a weird calculation).

Comment: Can't see the update - did you update your question, or my answer?

Comment: I put it in the question. I'll try putting it in here.

Comment: `beforeSend: function () {
              var batch_remainder = Math.max(0, ((batch_count + 1) * batch_size) - total_count);
              var percent = Math.round(((((batch_count + 1) * batch_size) - batch_remainder) / total_count) * 100);
              progress(percent);`

Comment: sorry, doesn't look like it has formatting. Unfortunately I need to log off... Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, or achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178860/discussion-between-egauvin-and-dacre-denny).